# How to get grails test-app to keep class files after run?

Tags: grails

Grails version 2.5.5

I need `grails test-app` to keep the class files around after it runs. I have the following configuration:

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
```

I ran `grails compile`, and the class files are in `target/classes`, then I run `grails test-app -unit` and for some reason it deletes the `target/classes` directory. I need these files for Sonar analysis.

How can I make `test-app` keep the class files, or at least keep the copies that it compiled?

Comment: which version of grails are you using?

Comment: why don't you just copies that file after `compilation` only?

Comment: @AmanNagarkoti I update the question to have the grails version

Comment: I searched a lot for is there is something in the framework which would implicitly make copies of classes, but didn't found any suitable answer, I will research this and get back to you, till then you have to copy them manually.

Comment: For the time being, I am running compile again after I run test-app.

Answer (score 0):

found something, follow the link:-

http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/grails-clean-build-deleted-classes-target-folder